# Can a judge make the plaintiff pay defender's legal costs?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, trial, punishment, costs

Two related questions. Situation is, Bob sues Alice, but has zero evidence (basically, extortion, hoping Alice settles to avoid legal costs and a trial). Alice decides to take things to court.

In the course of the trial, the judge decides that Bob has no case due to lack of any evidence corroborating the accusations.

- First, in purely legal terms, does a judge have leeway to make the plaintiff (Bob) pay for Alice's legal costs defending the suit at all?
- Second, does the judge generally have any leeway to punish Bob for bringing a clearly baseless lawsuit to court in other ways?
- Lastly, if either one is a "yes", does that actually happen with any frequency?

Jurisdiction: USA, if individual states differ let's say New York. But I'm also interested in "national standard baseline" if one exists, e.g. what do majority of states do.

I'm OK if the answer says "Judge can't do himself BUT can do so if defender's attorney makes a motion for that" - as long as it's part of the same trial/case.

Comment: This happens often when a countersuit is filed, so you may want to clarify if you mean purely at the judge's discretion if Alice's attorney doesn't think to make a counterclaim.

Comment: Note that outside the US, the loser paying the winner’s costs is the norm, not the exception.

Comment: @MichaelHall - is the countersuit part of "the same case"? If not, then yes I meant judge's actions in **original** case only

Comment: Hi. Your first paragraph starts with "Bob sues Alice" but then moves on to "Alice decides to take things to court". Do you mean that Alice actively engages in a countersuit?

Comment: @Stef I believe OP is just saying that Alice chooses to continue with litigation, rather than quickly settling the case that Bob filed.

Comment: @bdb484 - precisely

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

A federal court may impose sanctions for any filing that violates [Rule 11](https://casetext.com/statute/united-states-code/title-28-appendix/federal-rules-of-civil-procedure/title-iii-pleadings-and-motions/rule-11-signing-pleadings-motions-and-other-papers-representations-to-the-court-sanctions) of the Federal Rules of Civil Procedure, which imposes the following requirements on every filing:

> (1) it is not being presented for any improper purpose, such as to harass, cause unnecessary delay, or needlessly increase the cost of litigation;
>
> (2) the claims, defenses, and other legal contentions are warranted by existing law or by a nonfrivolous argument for extending, modifying, or reversing existing law or for establishing new law;
>
> (3) the factual contentions have evidentiary support or, if specifically so identified, will likely have evidentiary support after a reasonable opportunity for further investigation or discovery;
>
> (4) the denials of factual contentions are warranted on the evidence or, if specifically so identified, are reasonably based on belief or a lack of information.

Fee shifting -- forcing one party to pay for the other's lawyer -- is probably the paradigmatic example of a Rule 11 sanction. But the rule also allows sanctions in the form of a payment to the court itself, or "nonmonetary directives," which could include striking a filing in part or in whole, dismissing a case, granting default judgment, or ordering a lawyer to take additional classes.

And if he's really ticked off the judge, a lawyer may be required to:

> copy out, legibly, in his own handwriting, and within 30 days of the date hereof, the text ( i.e., without footnotes ) of section 3722 in 14A C. Wright, A. Miller, and E. Cooper, Federal Practice and Procedure: Civil (1985), together with the text of that section's update at page 43 of the 1993 pocket part of volume 14A [and] turn in the resulting product to the Clerk of this Court, with a certification that it was made solely by himself and in his own handwriting.

[*Curran v. Price*, 150 F.R.D. 85, 87 (D. Md. 1993)](https://casetext.com/case/j-joseph-curran-jr-v-ronald-w-price).

(I don't have access to the 1985 edition, but the current version consists of about 32,000 words.)

[22 NYCRR 130-1.1](https://casetext.com/regulation/new-york-codes-rules-and-regulations/title-22-judiciary/subtitle-a-judicial-administration/chapter-i-standards-and-administrative-policies/subchapter-c-rules-of-the-chief-administrator-of-the-courts/part-130-costs-and-sanctions/subpart-130-1-awards-of-costs-and-imposition-of-financial-sanctions-for-frivolous-conduct-in-civil-litigation/section-130-11-costs-sanctions) imposes different standards, but seems to generally allow similar relief.

Sanctions are certainly not the norm, but nor are they uncommon. Judges usually don't like doing any more work than they have to, so you can expect them to get prickly if they learn you're deliberately wasting their time.

Comment: Or if you are a certain ex-lawyer, you might sue for a picture with "Wrong on so many levels" only to be struck with 6-figures for you **and** your client to pay the legal costs of the other side because you filed a frivolous lawsuit because you never checked the terms that applied to the picture when it was posted. Yes, it's a Liebowitz case.

Comment: OK dumb Q, but you say "federal court" - is that even applicable in civil cases where Bob sues Alice?

Comment: Yes. Depending on the nature of the case and the citizenship of the parties, Bobs frequently sue Alices in federal court. Trump's lawsuit against Secretary Clinton, for instance, was heard in federal court, and the judge ordered him to pay ~$1M in sanctions because it was so stupid.

Comment: @user0306 among others, Copyright is *always* a federal matter, and a diversity of jurisdictions between the suing and defending part gives automatic rise to federal court.

Comment: @trish Both of those assertions are incorrect. Both categories of cases must sometimes be litigated in state court.

Comment: @bdb484 [copyright can not be litigated in state court, **unless** it is in a counterclaim. You can not sue for copyright as the first actor in state court.](https://www.balough.com/copyright-counterclaim-may-proceed-in-state-court/)

Comment: @Trish That is different from what you just said, but it is also incorrect. You may wish to read your own source more closely.

Comment: @bdb484 Enlighten me and point to where a state court could have initial jurisdiction on an initial case with a copyright claim, where copyright is preempted from states?

Comment: [*Capitol Records v. Naxos*, 4 N.Y.3d 540, (N.Y. 2005)](https://casetext.com/case/capitol-records-inc-v-naxos-of-america) is probably the best example.

Comment: @bdb484 "*Defendant Naxos of America, Inc. ("Naxos") has moved under Rule 12(b)(6) of the Federal Rules of Civil Procedure, to dismiss the complaint of plaintiff Capitol Records, Inc. ("Capital")* [...] *For the reasons set forth below, the Naxos motion to dismiss is converted to a summary judgment motion and granted.* [...] *1. Applicable Law[...] Capitol thus maintains that it "asserts no federal copyright claim in this action." (Def's Opp. Mem. at 8 n. 7.) [...] 2. Capitol Has No Rights in the Original Recordings [...] 3. Naxos Has Not Competed Unfairly*

Comment: @bdb484 That case does not deal with a live copyright but treats the whole suit as an unfair competition case - not as a copyright case, which the Souther district of New York would have to remove to federal court.

Comment: Apologies -- I cited to the correct case but linked to the wrong one. The correct case is here: https://casetext.com/case/capitol-records-inc-v-naxos-of-america-inc-no-30-ny-4-5-2005

Comment: @bdb484 which is an extraordinate case: *In a certified question, the United States Court of Appeals for the Second Circuit asks us whether there is common-law copyright protection in New York for sound recordings made prior to 1972.* [...] *After noting that, under federal law, "it is entirely up to New York to determine the scope of its common law copyright with respect to pre-1972 sound recordings," the Second Circuit certified the following question to this Court: [...]* - That court looked at pre-1972 common law copyright only, and not the federal satute.

Comment: Yes, I've read it already.